# How to keep track of Form field changes in Flask-WTF?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have model with members field as shown below:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    --- some fields ---
    members = ListProperty(db.Key) # Using App Engine datastore as backend.
```

I am using Flask-WTFforms to create form using this model. While creating new Team, user will select some members in the form and save it. User can also edit the Team form and make changes to the members field(Can add or remove members). I wanted to check how many members added or deleted by comparing it with previous data stored in members field. Same applies for other fields also.

I used sessions to achieve this:

def edit_team(key):

```
k = db.Key(key)
team = db.get(k)
form = TeamForm(obj = team)
if not form.is_submitted(): # Indicates GET request
    session[str(g.user.user_id() + 'prev_members'] = form.members.data
if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(project)
    # I will use session data with new form.members.data to do further processing.
```

Is this the right way to handle this scenario? 
Thank you for any help..

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is

```
team = db.get(k)
form = TeamForm(obj = team)
```

if the request was `GET`, the object's data has to be loaded from the model. however, if the request was `POST` (or `PUT`, `PATCH`) it means that you need to read the request body to form to do proper updates on the model. it seems like you're using `k` variable as a key to the indicator of the model.

```
k = db.Key(key)
team = db.get(k)
if request.method == "GET":
    # create form from the model
    form = TeamForm(obj = team)

elif request.method == "POST":
    # update model with the form
    form = TeamForm() #flask-wtf automatically reads from request object
    # validate, update, delete, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My method works in the same way as yours. If validate_on_submit() is False, it is considered as GET request and form is constructed using form = TeamForm(obj=team), if validate_on_submit() is True it is considered as POST request. I would like to save form data in GET request and process it in POST request. Also I can keep track of what has changed.

More on validate_on_submit(): This method in turn calls form.is_submitted() and form.validate(). is_submitted() method is the one that differentiates GET from POST.